# How to run chrome browser in RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

My OP is Windows.

I have installed RSelenium and I want to open the chrome browser (default browser in RSelenium is Firefox)

I have download the google chrome driver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and latest version of selenium standalone server and I run it from command line using this `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar` in command line

after that in RStudio I run this:

```
startServer()
checkForServer()
mybrowser <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
mybrowser$open()
```

but it stacks in this:

```
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
```

it doesn't give any error. Any idea how can I open and use chrome browser? Could be possible to use the chrome of my system?

Comment: Did you try the vignette http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Basics . It outlines using Docker and also rsDriver in the appendix.

Comment: @jdharrison and as alternative solution it refers the standalone version I use. Did you try to open chrome and works in RSelenium? Any help or steps will be more than helpful for me because I have really stuck. Thank you

Comment: Did you solve it? How?

Answer (score 0):

try this one this should be work add selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar as external jar file,**Right click on project->properties->java build path->libraries->add external jar.**and update project and add in setup

WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

Comment: I use Linux Mint, and I can't find "java build path"